# How do I get my anchor tags working without access to some of the page html code?

Tags: html, anchor

I had the task of editing this webpage (http://tapor.ca/pages/about_tapor) to add a side navigation bar with hyperlinks that link to different areas of the same webpage. I used CSS and anchor tags and I tested the webpage (html document saved on my computer) in my browser and the side navigation links worked perfectly. But when I cut and pasted the html code to the website 'server', it displays correctly but no link works. From my editing window, I don't have access to edit the top menu and footers of the webpage. I can only modify the space that starts with "About TAPoR 3.0" to the last words of the text "Stéfan Sinclair, McGill University."

I will appreciate if someone could visit the website and look at the html code and tell me what I can do to make the within page hyperlinks work. Below is the code I edited to add the side navigation bar.

Thanks a lot

```html
<div style="width: 190px; position: fixed; z-index: 1; /* stay on top */  top: 200px; left: 0; background-color: #fffaf0; overflow-x: hidden; /* disable horizontal scroll */  padding-top: 20px; font-size: 18px; margin-left: 20px;"><a href="#topnav">About TAPoR 3.0</a> <br /><br /> <a href="#redi">TAPoR Redesign</a><br /><br /> <a href="#tadi">TaDiRAH Taxonomy</a><br /><br /> <a href="#whywe">Why we Include Tools</a><br /><br /> <a href="#contri">Contribute</a></div>
<div style="margin-left: 195px;">
<h2 id="topnav">About TAPoR 3.0</h2>
<div>TAPoR is a gateway to the tools used in sophisticated text analysis and retrieval. Please contribute! (See below for ways to contribute.)</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>The project is led by <a href="http://www.geoffreyrockwell.com/">Geoffrey Rockwell</a>, <a href="http://stefansinclair.name/">St&eacute;fan Sinclair</a>, and <a href="http://research.mtroyal.ca/research-at-mru/researcher-profiles/?action=view&amp;type=researchers&amp;rid=1212">Milena Radzikowska</a> and housed at the University of Alberta. Support for this project came from <a href="https://www.westgrid.ca/">Compute Canada Calcul: Westgrid</a> the <a href="http://circa.ualberta.ca/">Canadian Institute for Research Computing in the Arts</a>, <a href="https://uofa.ualberta.ca/arts">University of Alberta</a>, the <a href="http://www.sshrc-crsh.gc.ca/default.htm">Social Science and Humanities Research Council</a> and the <a href="http://www.innovation.ca/en">Canada Foundation for Innovation</a>.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>The previous versions of TAPoR (version 1.0 and 2.0) are no longer available. Please contact us if you want access.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>Interface design by Milena Radzikowska. Others who have contributed significantly include Kirsten Uszkalo, James Chartrand (and Open Sky Solutions), Omar Rodriquez-Arenas, Kamal Ranaweera, Mark McKellar, Amy Dyrbye, Kaitlyn Grant, Holly H. Pickering, Chaolan Wu, Jingwei Wang, Kynan Ly, Antony Owino, Jason Bradshaw, Jinman Zhang, Robert Budac, Quinn Dombrowski, Shawn Day, and Lisa Goddard.&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div><strong> With TAPoR 3.0 you can: </strong></div>
<div>
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li>Discover text manipulation, analysis, and visualization tools</li>
<li>Discover historic tools</li>
<li>Read tool reviews and recommendations</li>
<li>Learn about papers, articles and other sources about specific tools</li>
<li>Tag, comment, rate, and review collaboratively</li>
<li>Browse lists of related tools in order to discover tools more easily</li>
</ul>
<div><strong>The TAPoR 3.0 redesign aimed to:</strong></div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Improve tool discovery interface</li>
<li>Improve engagement with text analysis tools</li>
<li>Focus on the discovery and social use of text analysis tools</li>
<li>Better communicate information about text analysis tools</li>
<li>Provide an Application Programming Interface to other services</li>
<li>Gather and reflect data about tool usage use</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<h2 id="redi"><strong>TAPoR Redesign </strong></h2>
<div>We have recently redesigned TAPoR in order to integrate the DiRT (Digital Research Tools) Directory. The integration was managed by Kaitlyn Grant with help from Quinn Dombrowski and programming by&nbsp;Omar Rodriquez-Arenas.&nbsp;</div>
<h5>&nbsp;</h5>
<div>
<h2 id="tadi"><strong>TaDiRAH Taxonomy</strong></h2>
<p>With the integration of DiRT Directory, TAPoR has made use of the TaDiRAH Goals &amp; Methods tags, to better cateogrize the tools.&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQNCfQeEXyAvxhVWFQr40gJ2Ze_M4s4DTI7NLvm9lzeRUgBz2mWZVWmTz1rVA2-mbCZreSxb4lmmW4W/pub">Click here</a>&nbsp;to see TaDiRAH Taxonomy's Goals &amp; Methods explained. For more information about TaDiRAH Taxonomy, visit&nbsp; <a href="http://tadirah.dariah.eu">http://tadirah.dariah.eu</a></p>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<h2 id="whywe"><strong>Why we include tools</strong></h2>
<div>TAPoR was originally created to be a directory only of tools used for text analysis. TAPoR has evolved to its current iteration, TAPoR 3.0 to include a far greater range of tools including code snippets that can do the work of tools. In 2018 TAPoR absorbed the DiRT project (Digital Research Tools) and now includes tools that work on non-textual data and tools that provide services used by digital humanists. This evolution largely reflects that of the field of digital humanities. Below are some broad domains of tools and services we now include in TAPoR with some examples.</div>
<h4>Publishing Tools</h4>
<div>
<p>The rise in the use of information and communication technology has brought about new ways of publishing information, including research. Publishing tools are used by digital humanists to share research and to create new types of online research resources. Examples:</p>
<ul>
<li>Open Journal Systems <a href="tools/1422">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1422)</a> is a free journal management and publishing system.</li>
<li>BuddyPress <a href="tools/1433">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1433)</a> is a variant of WordPress that includes social networking features.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Communication Tools</h4>
<div>Many humanities disciplines deal with human expression and communication. For this reason we use and study communication tools, especially those that propose novel ways of communicating or managing digital humanities projects. Examples: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>Slack <a href="tools/854">(http://tapor.ca/tools/854)</a> is a team-based communication and archiving platform.</li>
<li>Basecamp <a href="tools/916">(http://tapor.ca/tools/916)</a> is a project management software for sharing files, messages, task management and real time document editing.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Repositories and Archiving Tools</h4>
<div>Digital humanists create digital research resources, many of which are made available to the public for free use. Repositories and archiving tools are useful for building and maintaining research resources. Individual digital archives also become tools for further research. Examples: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>Adlib Archive <a href="tools/781">(http://tapor.ca/tools/781)</a> is an archive management system that helps institutions make their collections available online.</li>
<li>Twitter Archiver <a href="tools/592">(http://tapor.ca/tools/592)</a> is a tool (Python code) for archiving data from Twitter.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>GIS Tools</h4>
<div>Digital humanists now commonly use Geographical Information Systems to visualize spatial data. Research can be explored by geographical region using GIS. Example: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>GeoNode <a href="tools/1539">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1539)</a> is an open source geospatial content managing system.</li>
<li>MapAList <a href="tools/1538">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1538)</a> is a wizard for creating and managing customized Google maps of address lists.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Browser Extensions</h4>
<div>Browsers are the main gateways used to access resources over the internet. Most browsers allow the addition of extensions. Extensions permit more customization which increase the functionality of the browsers. Many extensions are useful to digital humanist and were created by them. Example: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>Hypothes.is <a href="tools/544">(http://tapor.ca/tools/544)</a> is a public annotation tool that works on almost all websites. Sub communities can be created for group annotations.</li>
<li>MyStickies <a href="tools/1106">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1106)</a> allows users to paste virtual sticky notes on websites which reappear each time the user visits the website.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Photo/Video/Audio Editor and Related Tools</h4>
<div>The humanities are not only concerned with text. Music deals with sound and in history images are frequently studied. Digital humanists in these fields use tools to edit, analyse, produce and publish multimedia objects. Example: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>Photogrammar <a href="tools/816">(http://tapor.ca/tools/816)</a> is a platform developed in Yale University for searching and organising a collection of over 170,000 historic images.</li>
<li>Express Scribe Transcription Software <a href="tools/1137">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1137)</a> is an audio playback software used for transcription.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h4>Development Tools</h4>
<div>Digital humanists develop resources and tools. For this reason we are interested in development tools that are useful specifically for digital humanities development. Example: &nbsp;
<ul>
<li>Adobe Dreamweaver <a href="tools/1250">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1250)</a> is used for creating, publishing, and managing websites and mobile content.</li>
<li>Ruby on Rails <a href="tools/1384">(http://tapor.ca/tools/1384)</a> for creating and hosting database driven websites.</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>The domains discussed are just main examples and are far from exhaustive considering the continuous creation of new tools and services and the changes in digital humanities.</div>
<h2 id="contri">Contribute</h2>
<div>We have designed TAPoR 3.0 so you can contribute.
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li>If you like a tool please use the rating system to vote for it.</li>
<li>Registered users can add tags to help people find and understand tools.</li>
<li>If you have something to say about a tool please enter a comment on the tool. You can use this to tell us how you use the tool, tell people about bugs, ask for features or link to related materials. An account is now required to leave a comment. Please contact the TAPoR team for an account.</li>
<li>Create lists of tools that you use together or that complement each other. Again an account is needed.</li>
<li>If you want to add a tool or write a longer review please email us: <a href="mailto:grockwel@ualberta.ca">Geoffrey Rockwell</a>, University of Alberta; or <a href="mailto:stefan.sinclair@mcgill.ca">St&eacute;fan Sinclair</a>, McGill University.</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Associate Editors Needed</strong></p>
<p>We are looking for Associate Editors who would take on the management of an annotated list around a&nbsp;specific discipline, need, audience, theme or technology. If selected you would add entries for tools that fit the profile and manage a list with annotations that guide people. Send a short proposal to&nbsp;<a href="mailto:grockwel@ualberta.ca">Geoffrey Rockwell</a>, University of Alberta; or&nbsp;<a href="mailto:stefan.sinclair@mcgill.ca">St&eacute;fan Sinclair</a>, McGill University.</p>
</div>
</div>
```